# Calling a REST API from the same server

Tags: php, json, api, https

I currently have a working JSON producing API producing URLs such as https://example.com/api/user/id/0

I am looking for the best method to internally call the API without the HTTPS processing time from PHP.

This works:

```
$url = "https://example.com/api/user/id/0";
file_get_contents($url);
```

This doesn't:

```
$url = "/api/user/id/0";
file_get_contents($url);
```

or this:

```
$url = __DIR__."/api/user/id/0";
file_get_contents($url);
```

I have a .htaccess file like this within the API currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The information from the apache error log is rather unhelpful:

```
file_get_contents(/api/user/id/0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var.....
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I currently receive a 5 second wait time per request using the full URL method even though the API is displayed in a fraction of a second when access directly. This is all native PHP, no frameworks.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is primarily used to get **file contents**, it won't magically understand that `/api/...` is supposed to be an HTTP call. At the very least you need to use `http://localhost/api/...` to make that explicit.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, the localhost redirects to a different subdomain by default so only the FQDN picks up. Nice suggestion though

Comment: Well, that's up to you and your web server to figure out. :)

Comment: I will test it out on a test machine later on and see if this works. It could be the answer as a workaround while there are no REST import features in PHP (or nothing anyone has suggested yet). Would cURL be faster than file_get_contents() possibly?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research into cURL as an alternative to file_get_contents()

David walsh's website (https://davidwalsh.name/curl-download) gave me a nice get function

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

So I ran this:

```
echo $url ."<br>";
$fgt1 = time();
$file_get = file_get_contents($url, false);
$fgt2 = time();

$cgu1 = time();
$curl_get = get_data($url);
$cgu2 = time();

$fgt = $fgt2 - $fgt1;
$cgu = $cgu2 - $cgu1;
echo "<br>file_get_contents(): {$fgt}<br>curl: {$cgu}";
```

The response for the curl function came back almost instantaneously and the file_get_contents() function came back at 5 seconds. I hope this helps someone else looking to pull data from a JSON API on HTTPS.

I now need to investigate sending different header methods via curl such as POST and DELETE but I suspect it'll be in there somewhere.

Thanks for any suggestions that were made (and deleted). It helped.